# How to change a sentence with two objects into passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

> ***(1) He gave her some money.***

Its passive voice is:

- (2) She was given some money.
- (3) Some money was given her.

> ***(4) He gave some money to her.***

Its passive voice is :

- (5) She was given some money ***to***.
- (6) Some money was given to her.

Which sentence above is correct? How to change a sentence with two objects into passive voice?

Comment: the passive is *she was given some money **by him**.*

Comment: First, you have to decide which object you want to make the subject. Then, you put it into passive voice. Result: **either** *She was given some money (by him).* **or** *Some money was given (to her) (by him)*. If this is a test, and only one answer is valid, your guess as to what they want is as good as mine.

Comment: Try this - http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/passive_two_objects.htm

Answer (score 1):

Number (2) is fine, correct and natural.

Number (3) should say, 'Some money was given **to** her.'

Number (5) is close, but the 'to' should be replaced with 'by him': 'She was given some money by him.' However, you could omit both so it's exactly the same as Number (2).

Number (6) is fine, correct and natural.

As for the best way to get this into the passive voice, I would say 'She was given some money by him' is your best option.

Comment: #3 is perfectly grammatical, and natural in many dialects and registers.

Answer (score 0):

(1) He gave her some money.

### Answer:

She was given by him some money.

(4) He gave some money to her.

### Answer:

Some money was given by him to her.

Comment: "She was given _by him_ some money." Although this may be technically grammatical, it is an awkward construction - almost makes the verb seem intransitive.  It is much more common for the direct object to follow the verb: _She was given some money by him._ Same goes for the second sentence.