# Is there no object in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, objects

As the object of active voice becomes the subject of passive voice and the subject of active voice comes after preposition by.(and sometimes dropped)
I dont think there is an object there. Right?

Comment: Consider clauses with both a direct and an indirect object. *The clerk gave the lawyer a message* can become *The lawyer was given a message by the clerk*, retaining its object. *[How to change a sentence with two objects into passive voice?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/19480)*, *[Active voice to passive voice. Ditransitive verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/41450)*, and *[Question concerning a prepositional phrase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/87722)* may be informative regarding sentences of this structure.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on how you parse the passive voice. The verb that really tells you what it means, together with any indirect object of that verb, could be thought of as the object, and the "object" of that verb as the subject - and the verb is "to be".

If you think of the passivised verb as the principle verb, then there an object but no subject.